# Can't Install SOA Composite Editor in JDeveloper - Orace SOA Suite 12c

Tags: oracle, macos, jdeveloper, soa-suite

I've installed the Oracle SOA Suite 12c and the installation went fine. When I try to install the Oracle SOA Composite Editor in JDeveloper something goes wrong, it says I finished the install, but when JDeveloper restarts I still can't select a project from the SOA tier.

I'm working on a MAC OS X 10.10.2 and use the JDeveloper Studio Edition Version 12.1.3.0.0.

Hopefully someone could help me to fix this problem!

Comment: If the installation is complete, chose to not restart. Then close your JDeveloper and open it again (so you perform a manual restart).

Comment: @Vincent Have you found the solution? I also stuck with the same.

Answer (score 0):

SOA Suite editor is not supported on the mac in JDeveloper. Windows and Linux only. The only FMW products that runs on Mac is WebLogic. JDeveloper Studio with ADF and Mobile Application Framework run on the Mac.